# WSAECONNRESET (10054) error using WebDrive to map to a Subversion/Apache WebDAV share

Tags: svn, ldap, webdav, mod-dav-svn

I'm using WebDrive to map a drive letter to a WebDAV share running on Subversion with the SVNAutoversioning flag enabled. The Subversion server is running CollabNet Subversion Edge with LDAP authentication.

When trying to connect using WebDrive, I get:

```
Connecting to site myserver
Connecting to http://myserver/webdrive/
Resolving url myserver to an IP address
Url resolved to IP address 192.168.0.12
Connecting to 192.168.0.12 on port 80
Connected successfully to the server on port 80
Testing directory listing ...
Connecting to 192.168.0.12 on port 80
Connected successfully to the server on port 80

Unable to connect to server, error information below

Error: Socket receive failure (4507)
Operation: Connecting to server
Winsock Error: WSAECONNRESET (10054)
```

The httpd.conf file running on the server contains the following section:

```
<Location /webdrive/>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath "C:\Program Files\Subversion\data\repositories"
    SVNReposName "My Subversion WebDrive"
    AuthzSVNAccessFile "C:\Program Files\Subversion\data/conf/svn_access_file"
    SVNListParentPath On
    Allow from all
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "My Subversion Repository"
    AuthBasicProvider csvn-file-users ldap-users
    Require valid-user
    ModMimeUsePathInfo on
    SVNAutoversioning on
</Location>
```

and in the Apache error_yyyy_mm_dd.log file on the server, I'm seeing this when I try to connect via WebDAV:

```
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:22 2011] [debug] mod_authnz_ldap.c(379): [client 192.168.0.50] [5572] auth_ldap authenticate: using URL ldap://mydc/dc=mydomain,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:22 2011] [debug] mod_authnz_ldap.c(484): [client 192.168.0.50] [5572] auth_ldap authenticate: accepting dylan.beattie
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:22 2011] [info] [client 192.168.0.50] Access granted: 'dylan.beattie' OPTIONS webdrive:/
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:22 2011] [debug] mod_authnz_ldap.c(379): [client 192.168.0.50] [5572] auth_ldap authenticate: using URL ldap://mydc/dc=mydomain,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:22 2011] [debug] mod_authnz_ldap.c(484): [client 192.168.0.50] [5572] auth_ldap authenticate: accepting dylan.beattie
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:22 2011] [info] [client 192.168.0.50] Access granted: 'dylan.beattie' PROPFIND webdrive:/
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:25 2011] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:25 2011] [debug] util_ldap.c(1990): LDAP merging Shared Cache conf: shm=0xcd0f18 rmm=0xcd0f48 for VHOST: myserver.mydomain.com
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:25 2011] [debug] util_ldap.c(1990): LDAP merging Shared Cache conf: shm=0xcd0f18 rmm=0xcd0f48 for VHOST: myserver.mydomain.com
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:25 2011] [info] APR LDAP: Built with Microsoft Corporation. LDAP SDK
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:25 2011] [info] LDAP: SSL support unavailable: LDAP: CA certificates cannot be set using this method, as they are stored in the registry instead.
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:25 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Win32) DAV/2 SVN/1.6.13 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:25 2011] [notice] Server built: Oct  4 2010 19:55:36
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:25 2011] [notice] Parent: Created child process 4368
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:25 2011] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(487): Parent: Sent the scoreboard to the child
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:25 2011] [debug] util_ldap.c(1990): LDAP merging Shared Cache conf: shm=0xca2bb0 rmm=0xca2be0 for VHOST: myserver.mydomain.com
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:25 2011] [debug] util_ldap.c(1990): LDAP merging Shared Cache conf: shm=0xca2bb0 rmm=0xca2be0 for VHOST: myserver.mydomain.com
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:25 2011] [info] APR LDAP: Built with Microsoft Corporation. LDAP SDK
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:25 2011] [info] LDAP: SSL support unavailable: LDAP: CA certificates cannot be set using this method, as they are stored in the registry instead.
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:25 2011] [error] python_init: Python version mismatch, expected '2.5', found '2.5.4'.
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:25 2011] [error] python_init: Python executable found 'C:\\Program Files\\Subversion\\bin\\httpd.exe'.
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:25 2011] [error] python_init: Python path being used 'C:\\Program Files\\Subversion\\Python25\\python25.zip;C:\\Program Files\\Subversion\\Python25\\\\DLLs;C:\\Program Files\\Subversion\\Python25\\\\lib;C:\\Program Files\\Subversion\\Python25\\\\lib\\plat-win;C:\\Program Files\\Subversion\\Python25\\\\lib\\lib-tk;C:\\Program Files\\Subversion\\bin'.
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:25 2011] [notice] mod_python: Creating 8 session mutexes based on 0 max processes and 64 max threads.
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:25 2011] [notice] Child 4368: Child process is running
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:25 2011] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(408): Child 4368: Retrieved our scoreboard from the parent.
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:25 2011] [info] Parent: Duplicating socket 288 and sending it to child process 4368
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:25 2011] [info] Parent: Duplicating socket 276 and sending it to child process 4368
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:25 2011] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(564): Child 4368: retrieved 2 listeners from parent
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:25 2011] [notice] Child 4368: Acquired the start mutex.
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:25 2011] [notice] Child 4368: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:25 2011] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(605): Parent: Sent 2 listeners to child 4368
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:25 2011] [notice] Child 4368: Starting thread to listen on port 49159.
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:25 2011] [notice] Child 4368: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:25 2011] [debug] mod_authnz_ldap.c(379): [client 192.168.0.50] [4368] auth_ldap authenticate: using URL ldap://mydc/dc=mydomain,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:25 2011] [debug] mod_authnz_ldap.c(484): [client 192.168.0.50] [4368] auth_ldap authenticate: accepting dylan.beattie
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:25 2011] [info] [client 192.168.0.50] Access granted: 'dylan.beattie' PROPFIND webdrive:/
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:28 2011] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:28 2011] [debug] util_ldap.c(1990): LDAP merging Shared Cache conf: shm=0xcd4f90 rmm=0xcd4fc0 for VHOST: myserver.mydomain.com
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:28 2011] [debug] util_ldap.c(1990): LDAP merging Shared Cache conf: shm=0xcd4f90 rmm=0xcd4fc0 for VHOST: myserver.mydomain.com
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:28 2011] [info] APR LDAP: Built with Microsoft Corporation. LDAP SDK
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:28 2011] [info] LDAP: SSL support unavailable: LDAP: CA certificates cannot be set using this method, as they are stored in the registry instead.
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:28 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Win32) DAV/2 SVN/1.6.13 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:28 2011] [notice] Server built: Oct  4 2010 19:55:36
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:28 2011] [notice] Parent: Created child process 5440
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:28 2011] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(487): Parent: Sent the scoreboard to the child
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:28 2011] [debug] util_ldap.c(1990): LDAP merging Shared Cache conf: shm=0xda2bb0 rmm=0xda2be0 for VHOST: myserver.mydomain.com
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:28 2011] [debug] util_ldap.c(1990): LDAP merging Shared Cache conf: shm=0xda2bb0 rmm=0xda2be0 for VHOST: myserver.mydomain.com
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:28 2011] [info] APR LDAP: Built with Microsoft Corporation. LDAP SDK
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:28 2011] [info] LDAP: SSL support unavailable: LDAP: CA certificates cannot be set using this method, as they are stored in the registry instead.
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:28 2011] [error] python_init: Python version mismatch, expected '2.5', found '2.5.4'.
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:28 2011] [error] python_init: Python executable found 'C:\\Program Files\\Subversion\\bin\\httpd.exe'.
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:28 2011] [error] python_init: Python path being used 'C:\\Program Files\\Subversion\\Python25\\python25.zip;C:\\Program Files\\Subversion\\Python25\\\\DLLs;C:\\Program Files\\Subversion\\Python25\\\\lib;C:\\Program Files\\Subversion\\Python25\\\\lib\\plat-win;C:\\Program Files\\Subversion\\Python25\\\\lib\\lib-tk;C:\\Program Files\\Subversion\\bin'.
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:28 2011] [notice] mod_python: Creating 8 session mutexes based on 0 max processes and 64 max threads.
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:28 2011] [notice] Child 5440: Child process is running
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:28 2011] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(408): Child 5440: Retrieved our scoreboard from the parent.
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:28 2011] [info] Parent: Duplicating socket 288 and sending it to child process 5440
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:28 2011] [info] Parent: Duplicating socket 276 and sending it to child process 5440
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:28 2011] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(564): Child 5440: retrieved 2 listeners from parent
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:28 2011] [notice] Child 5440: Acquired the start mutex.
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:28 2011] [notice] Child 5440: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:28 2011] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(605): Parent: Sent 2 listeners to child 5440
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:28 2011] [notice] Child 5440: Starting thread to listen on port 49159.
[Mon Jan 10 14:53:28 2011] [notice] Child 5440: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

Browsing http://myserver/webdrive/ from a web browser is working fine, and I have a similar set-up working perfectly on a different SVN server that isn't running Collabnet but has had Subversion and Apache installed and configured separately.

Any ideas? The python version error might be red herring - I've seen it in a couple of places in the log files and in other scenarios it doesn't appear to be breaking anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved - thanks to [this post](http://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=3&dsMessageId=398290) on the CollabNet forums.

I was trying to connect to `http://myserver/webdrive/` - which won't work.

Add the name of a repository - `http://myserver/webdrive/reponame/` - on the end of the URL, and it connects without any problems.

Comment: Accept your answer and enjoy the rewards of figuring it out through another avenue.